# Querying for User Story detail using array of ObjectIDs

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I have been using the Lookback API to query for user stories from the Rally environment. While the querying functionality is stronger than the WsapiDataStore, by allowing me to query using the RPM hierarchy, it does not seem to be able to return full data fields' values, such as Owner and Project. Instead, the OIDs for these fields are returned. To try to work around this, my idea was to first do a Lookback API query to get all the story OIDs within the RPM hierarchy I am concerned with. I will capture the story OIDs and keep them in an array. Then, I can use a WsapiDataStore query to get the detailed info for the stories matching the OIDs in the array. When using the Lookback API, I have the option to use the 'in' operator, so the query would look like this:

```
{
    property: 'ObjectID',
    operator: 'in',
    value: [ '71352862', '44523976', '61138496' ]
}
```

I can't use this functionality in the WsapiDataStore however. Also, when I try to 'OR' them all together in one long query string I am getting an error about an invalid request. I assume the query string is too long since in most cases I am searching for about 1000 User Stories. I would prefer not to have to make a separate query for each OID but right now that is seeming like the only solution. Is there a way to get full details from the Lookback API, or at least filter using an array on the WsapiDataStore query?

Comment: With the WSAPI generating an OR query that has thousands of stories may not be your best bet. Can you cast a wide net with a regular query that will get you those stories and match up the ones you actually need in browser memory?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectID now supports the `in` operator.

From the [WSAPI docs](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/):

[image: ObjectID WSAPI documentation]

Here is an example usage: `(ObjectID in 1,2,3)`